# Why am i unable to save more than one record in the file(binary mode) using turbo c++?

Tags: c++, file-handling, file-writing, turbo-c++

declared class is "Elements" object is "e"

```
void input() //WRITING RECORD**
{
    fstream f;
    Element e;
    f.open("ELEMENT.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
    char ch;
    do{
        e.getinfo();
        f.write((char*)&e,sizeof(e));
        cout<<"\n More Records?";
        cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y');
    f.close();
}
```

Whenever I write more than 1 record in a file, only the first record is stored and the rest do not appear. [FILE HANDLING, TURBO C++]

Is it a logical mistake or there is a need of adding a new syntax?

Comment: For binary mode you should open with `ios::binary`. Show the definition of `Element` too.

Comment: `cin>>ch` also reads whitespace, unless I remember wrong. So your loop ends at the enter you used to imput first y. To test, enter yyyy, and see if 4 records are saved.

Comment: Many ways to solve this. Does Turbo C++ have `std::string`? If so, read strings instead of chars, that skips whitespace. Or, write `read_from_cin_until_newline()` function to ignore remaining line and newline.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'd done trying ios::binary earlier but there wasn't any change.

Comment: @hyde no change, tried to read string instead of char. Please demonstrate me read_from_cin_until_newline().

Comment: Just write that function name in C++... do read character from cin while cin ok and chatacter is not newline

Comment: @hyde Turbo-C++ is so old it might not have a standard library. See wikipedia for it's history. It's a pity they still teach it as schools